# How to use a declared variable that contains a table name, as a join in a for loop. Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

The name of a materialized view I want to use as part of some SQL in a stored procedure, is held within a table. I need to get the name of the table stored in a variable so that the procedure can use it. The part that will receive the table name is in a for loop. How can I use a variable in the loop?

This is an example of what I mean:

```
declare
l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';
V_MV_NAME varchar2(2000);

begin

SELECT mv_name into V_MV_NAME 
FROM track_mv
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from track_mv);

for rws in (

  select /*+parallel (4)*/ a.owner,a.table_name, round(sum(b.sum_bytes),2)  TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB, EST_ONE_ROW_MB
    from dba_tables@DB1 a, MAT_VIEW_ANON b
    where a.table_name = b.segment_name

and a.table_name in
(select table_name from BOB_TABLE where driver_table is null)
and a.owner in (select distinct schema from BOB_TABLE c)
group by a.owner,a.table_name
order by a.table_name
)
loop...
```

Here, V_MV_NAME holds the variable. I want to use that variable in the body of the query:

```
for rws in (

  select /*+parallel (4)*/ a.owner,a.table_name, round(sum(b.sum_bytes),2)  TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB, EST_ONE_ROW_MB
    from dba_tables@DB1 a, MAT_VIEW_ANON b
    where a.table_name = b.segment_name
```

So it may read something like this:

```
from dba_tables@DB1 a, ||V_MV_NAME|| 'b'
```

Or similar. The code is already in place with the hard coded values. This would be the simplest thing to do if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

> The name of a materialized view I want to use as part of some SQL in a stored procedure, is held within a table

This is a bad idea. It won't scale, you have to switch your code to dynamic SQL which is ugly and hard to maintain. For simple cases it is ... ah, OK, kind of acceptable, but for something like you have - huh, I wouldn't want to do that.

I suggest you find another way.

Why would you want to do it, anyway? Use materialized view name *as is*, not stored in some table.

Comment: I did change it to dynamic sql, stored the whole statement in a v_sql variable and then did for rws in (v_sql) loop but I later call items within the loop, like rws.table_name... and it doesn't recognise that. There's not much data in this whole thing, I just want it to work as is if possible, this thing has grown organically and a redesign can be done if necessary but getting where it is now has been time consuming and that is a constraint just now

Comment: OK. If it does what you wanted it to do, and if you're satisfied with what you get, that would be it. As far as I can tell, dynamic SQL is the only way to do it.